# Foursquare Comments Retrieval

Tags: foursquare

Foursquare added support for comments and i was able to post the comments using the endpoint:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/ID/addcomment

But the comments are not displayed in the response to the recent checkins endpoint.

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/checkins/recent

It displays the number of comments with an empty list.

comments: {
count: 5
items: [ ]
}

Is it a problem in the Foursquare API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including the comment count but not the actual comments is a deliberate performance optimization. It's a decision we may revisit in the future, but in general you should be prepared for this sort of pattern where an empty or small items array accompanies a non-zero or larger count value. In all these cases, there should be some additional call you can make to get the information (in this case, the checkin details call).

Comment: thanks. Yes, i could able to retrieve the comments using the checkin details request.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is a privacy setting.

You can only see the comments on a check-in if the OAuthed user (whose key you are using) is friends with the person checking-in.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to retrieve the comments from the friends of the OAuthed user. But still it does not return the comments in the recent checkins.